# How to swipe Left and Right with vertical scrolling using ScrollView in Android

Tags: android

I have some layouts inside a scrollView. Those layouts have to be swipable in left and right directions but it creates some conflicts with the scroll View. How can use both swipe and scroll using ScrollView in Android. I don,t want to use ViewPager.

Please help me as i am fresher in android.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please post your xml file?

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HorizontalScrollView` to scroll your `child views` horizontally and place this `HorizontalScrollView` inside `ScrollView`. Also add `LinearLayout` with `Vertical` orientation as a direct child of `ScrollView`.

**Here is an working example. Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- First row -->
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="One"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="Two"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="Three"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <!-- Second row -->
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="One"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="Two"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="Three"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <!-- Third row -->
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="One"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="Two"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:text="Three"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `HorizontalScrollView`, which scrolls left-right, inside your parent `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="your_width" android:layout_height="your_height" >

 <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="your_width" android:layout_height="your_height">

</HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```